# integrand() missing 1 required positional argument integration

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to do following Integration

[image]

Where `e = 1.602e-19` is the elementary charge in Coulombs,
`kb = 1.381e-23` is the Boltzmann constant in J/K,
`T = 300` is the temperature in Kelvin and `mu=0.5`

I have array of E vs DOS Data

```
E DOS
-18.68526 11.5535
-17.05825 10.53234
-15.43124 14.4706
-13.80423 10.63194
-12.17723 12.04803
-10.55022 9.51133
-8.92321 12.07561
-7.2962 25.97326
-5.6692 26.43385
-4.04219 21.97081
-2.41518 14.23236
-0.78817 5.39077
0.83883 3.17652
2.46584 13.11387
4.09285 12.40104
5.71986 13.84468
7.34686 19.24209
8.97387 34.36795
10.60088 30.42492
12.22789 26.10606
13.85489 32.17047
15.4819 34.89188
17.10891 30.86395
18.73592 0.02738
```

The current code I have

```
import openpyxl
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.signal import convolve

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='DOS.xlsx', data_only=True)
o_sheet = wb["Sheet1"]

# Get Values from First Column
E_data = [cell.value for col in o_sheet.iter_cols(min_col=1, max_col=1) for cell in col]
DOS_data = [cell.value for col in o_sheet.iter_cols(min_col=2, max_col=2) for cell in col]

del E_data[0]
del DOS_data[0]

DOS_data = np.array(DOS_data)
E_data = np.array(E_data)
E_data = E_data.astype(np.float64)
DOS = DOS_data.astype(np.float64)


e = 1.602e-19
kb = 1.381e-23
T = 300
mu=0.5

hbar = 1.05457182e10-34

E_min = E_data.min()
E_max = E_data.max()


def sech_func(E):

    return np.cosh(E / (2 * kb * T))**(-2)



def interpolate(E):

    DOS_E = np.interp(E, E_data, DOS_data)

    return DOS_E

# Integration function
def integrand(E,DOS_E):
      # Interpolate DOS at energy E
    return (interpolate(E)-mu)*sech_func(E) * DOS_E



x = np.linspace(E_min, E_max, 100)

y = interpolate(x)
y_sech= sech_func(y)
y_final = integrand(x,y)

# Quantum capacitance (F/m^2)
Cq = e**2 *((4 * kb * T)**(-1))* quad(integrand, E_min, E_max)[0]

print(f"Quantum capacitance: {Cq:.3e} F/m^2")
```

```
C:/Users/czm0131/Desktop/Opt/QC3.py:42: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in cosh
  return np.cosh(E / (2 * kb * T))**(-2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/Opt/QC3.py", line 66, in <module>
    Cq = e**2 *((4 * kb * T)**(-1))* quad(integrand, E_min, E_max)[0]
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 352, in quad
    points)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 463, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
TypeError: integrand() missing 1 required positional argument: 'DOS_E'
```

Comment: how's `integrand` supposed to get `DOS_E`?

Comment: Thank you I thought through y, '`y_final = integrand(x,y)`

Comment: `quad(integrand, E_min, E_max, args=(DOS_E,))` should solve this error.